# If A is projection, then I-2A is orthogonal.

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let A b real square matrix and $B = I - 2A$. Which of the following is
>   true?
>
> 1. If A is projection, then B is orthogonal.
> 2. If A is orthogonal projection, then B is orthogonal.

Both are true. Obviously, the 2nd statement is more restrictive than the 1st one, so it suffices to show the validity of the 1st statement.

B is orthogonal means that

$$ I =B^{T}B = (I-2A)^T (I-2A) = (I-2A^T) (I-2A) = I-2A -2A^T + 4A^TA = $$

$$= I-2A -2A^T + 4A^TA \Leftrightarrow 2A + 2A^T = 4A^TA \Leftrightarrow A + A^T = 2A^TA $$

Being projection implies that $AA=A$, so let's multiply both sides by A

$$AA + A^TA = 2A^TAA \Leftrightarrow A + A^TA = 2A^TA \Leftrightarrow A = A^TA $$

Also, if A is projection, than A^T is projection as well. Again, let's multiply both sides by $A^T$

$$ A^TA = A^T A^TA \Leftrightarrow A^TA = A^TA$$

which is true for any projection matrix. So, the 1st statement is true.

---

My problem is that (according to my textbook) the 1st statement is false, while the 2nd one is true. Where did I mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you only showed that for a projection $A$ the equation $A^t A = A^t A$ holds true. You have to show $A+A^t = 2A^tA$, which is not true for a general projection, and not 
$$ A^t(A + A^t)A = 2(A^t)^2A^2$$
(what you showed). Note that this is not the same, as a projection is not invertible (besides $A = {\rm Id}$, but this is an orthogonal projection).

Comment: Ok, so I showed the necessity, but not sufficiency. But how being orthogonal projection instead of just projection helps here?

Comment: An orthogonal projection has $A = A^t$ (real case), so $A+A^t = 2A = 2A^2 = 2A^tA$.

Comment: Right, it's symmetric! Now, I got it.

Answer (score 1):

(1) Is wrong: take
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix},
$$
then $A^2 = A$ and
$$
B = I-2A = \begin{pmatrix} -1 & 2 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
$$
is certainly not orthogonal.

(2) Assume $A$ to be orthogonal projection: then $A=A^T$ implying
$$
B^TB= (I-2A^T)(I-2A) = I - 2A^T - 2A + 4 A^TA = I - 4A + 4A^2 = I.
$$
Hence $B$ is orthogonal.